# Why would an access table primary key column contain a null?

Tags: ms-access, null, primary-key

Why would a MS Access table contains a null value. The table itself does not need to be in a relationship.

Comment: Well, How could we possibly solve the issue without getting a look at the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your table contains a Null value in the column you believe to be the primary key then you made a mistake creating the Primary Key and did not create it.

**A Primary Key cannot be NULL by definition.** This is enforced even by Access/ACE without any further attributes, like *NOT NULL* / *Required*.

The obvious thing you need to fix is to create the Primary Key.

If, against all odds, you actually, really defined a Primary Key on that column and still there is a Null value in it, then your database is corrupt and you should try to Compact/Repair the database.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because you didn't declare `NOT NULL` while creating the table. Declaring `Primary Key` constraint can only prevent data duplication. To prevent `Null` value entry, you must declare `NOT NULL` constraint

Answer (score 0):

You did not set primary key for that column. Your primary key column should should be auto incremented, primary and not null.

Comment: How do you auto-increment a Text value?